ESP32-CAM No funciona
He intentado tomar una foto con el modulo esp32-cam para poder mandarla a un servidor hecho con C#. Sin embargo, la instrucción de tomar la imagen parece no funcionar y no veo de donde puede venir el error. Además mi modulo no me permite escribir en el puerto serie, por eso utilizo la escritura mediante el wifi para recepcionar los mensajes en Visual Studio. Adjunto el código completo por si alguien viera el fallo, me seria de gran ayuda. Muchas gracias.
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "rom/ets_sys.h"
#include "freertos/semphr.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DEFINES
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Define Input
#define sensorES GPIO_NUM_15

// Define Output
#define aliveLed GPIO_NUM_2
#define alarmSignal GPIO_NUM_16
#define flash GPIO_NUM_4

// Define camera
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM    32  // Pin para el modo de ahorro de energía de la cámara. -1 indica que no se usa.
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM   -1  // Pin para reiniciar la cámara. -1 indica que no se usa.
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM    0   // Pin para la señal del reloj externo (XCLK) que se usa para sincronizar la cámara.
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM    26  // Pin para la línea de datos del bus I2C (SDA). Se usa para la configuración de la cámara.
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM    27  // Pin para la línea de reloj del bus I2C (SCL). También se usa para la configuración de la cámara.

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM      35  // Pin para la línea de datos Y9 de la cámara (uno de los bits del bus de datos de la cámara).
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM      34  // Pin para la línea de datos Y8 de la cámara.
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM      39  // Pin para la línea de datos Y7 de la cámara.
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM      36  // Pin para la línea de datos Y6 de la cámara.
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM      21  // Pin para la línea de datos Y5 de la cámara.
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM      19  // Pin para la línea de datos Y4 de la cámara.
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM      18  // Pin para la línea de datos Y3 de la cámara.
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM      5   // Pin para la línea de datos Y2 de la cámara.
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM   25  // Pin para la señal de sincronización vertical (VSYNC), que indica el final de una imagen.
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM    23  // Pin para la señal de referencia horizontal (HREF), que indica el comienzo de una nueva línea de píxeles.
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM    22  // Pin para la señal del reloj de píxeles (PCLK), que sincroniza la lectura de los píxeles.


// WiFi
const char* ssid = "******"; // Aqui tengo mi ssid
const char* wifiPassword = "****"; //Aqui tengo mi contraseña de WiFi

const char* serverIP = "***";  // Aqui tengo mi Ip
const uint16_t serverPort = 12345;
int tiempo = 1000;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TASKS
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Blink alive led
void GreenLedBlinkTask(void *pvParameters)
{
  while(1) {
    gpio_set_level(aliveLed, 0);
    //gpio_set_level(flash, 0);
    vTaskDelay(tiempo / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    gpio_set_level(aliveLed, 1);
    //gpio_set_level(flash, 1);
    vTaskDelay(tiempo / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MAIN
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200); 

  gpio_set_direction(sensorES, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);

  gpio_set_direction(aliveLed, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
  gpio_set_direction(flash, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
  gpio_set_direction(alarmSignal, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

  gpio_set_level(aliveLed, HIGH);
  gpio_set_level(flash, LOW);
  gpio_set_level(alarmSignal, HIGH);

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;

  //Conexion al Wifi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, wifiPassword);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
  }

  // Inicializar la cámara
  if (esp_camera_init(&config) != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error al inicializar la cámara");
    return;
  }

  // Tasks
  if (xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(GreenLedBlinkTask, "GBli", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY+1, NULL, 0) != pdPASS) {
    Serial.println("No se pudo crear la tarea GreenLedBlink");
  }
}


void loop(){

  WiFiClient client;
  
  if (client.connect(serverIP, serverPort)) {
    camera_fb_t* fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    if (!fb) {
      client.print("Error al capturar la imagen");
      //return;
    }

    String message = "control";
    client.print(message);


    // // Enviar la longitud de la imagen
    // client.write((const uint8_t*)&fb->len, sizeof(fb->len));
    // client.print("Tamaño de la imagen enviado");

    // // Enviar los datos de la imagen
    // client.write(fb->buf, fb->len);
    // client.print("Imagen enviada al servidor");

  }
  client.stop();

  // Cerrar la conexión

  delay(5000);
}

Hay partes que he ido comentando para intentar aislar el problema, parece que directamente no se esta tomando la imagen

Es complicado ayudarte sin ver los errores que puedan estar apareciendo. Te puedo sugerir que leas la documentación, verifiques que cumples los requisitos y pruebes alguno de los ejemplos. Luego incluye los errores en la pregunta https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera/blob/master/README.md
